# Extension of a generalized function to the plane

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, schwartz-distributions, generalized-functions

Let $\phi$ be a generalized function on $\mathbb{R}^2\backslash\{0\}$, and  assume that its differential $d\phi$ extends to the whole plane $\mathbb{R}^2$.

> **Q.** Does $\phi$ also extend to $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: Just to clarify: Generalized function is the same as distribution and by differential you mean the gradient, i.e. the vector of partial derivatives of the distribution?

Comment: I guess, this is answered in this post: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/extension+of+distributions

Comment: @Dirk: Yes, your first comment is correct. regarding your second comment, I do not see right now how it implies the positive answer to my question. But thanks for the reference, it is relevant.

Comment: Prop 3.1 in the reference by Dirk gives a sufficient condition for extendability. So Your question reduces to showing the degree of divergence of $\phi$ is finite from your hypothesis on the extendability of the derivatives.